# Compare file hashes every 10 seconds to evaluate if it has been modified or not

Tags: c#, file, asynchronous, hash, timer

I am trying to check to see if a given file has changed by checking every ten seconds and comparing the previous file hash to the file current hash ( see **FileHasChanged()** method ). If the hashes are different, it would indicate that the file has been modified.

When I run my code, however, I get the following error:

**System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified. Enumeration operation may not execute.**

I'm at a loss for how to get this working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class File : Subscribable
{
    private Dictionary<byte[], byte[]> FileHashes;
    private bool FileModified;
    private DateTime FileModifiedDate;
    private List<string> FileNames;
    private List<Observable> Observers;

    public File(List<string> fileNames)
    {
        FileHashes = new Dictionary<byte[], byte[]>();
        FileNames = new List<string>();
        Observers = new List<Observable>();

        foreach (var file in fileNames)
            FileNames.Add(file);

        var initializeHashesTimer = new Timer(LoadFileHashes, null, 0, 10000);
        var checkIfChangedTimer = new Timer(FileHasChanged, null, 10, 20000);
    }

    public void NotifyObservers()
    {
        foreach (var observer in Observers)
            observer.Update(FileModified, FileModifiedDate, FileNames);
    }

    public void RegisterObserver(Observable o)
    {
        Observers.Add(o);
    }

    public void RemoveObserver(Observable o)
    {
        int i = Observers.IndexOf(o);

        if (i >= 0)
            Observers.RemoveAt(i);
    }

    private void LoadFileHashes(object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loading file hashes... ");
        // For each file in a list of files, store the file hash.
        foreach (var file in FileNames)
        {
            var hash = GetFileHash(file);
            FileHashes.Add(hash, null);
        }
    }

    private void FileHasChanged(object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Checking to see if file has been modified... ");
        var values = new List<byte[]>();

        // In ten seconds, store the file hash again.
        foreach (var file in FileNames)
        {
            var hash = GetFileHash(file);
            values.Add(hash);
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<byte[], byte[]> entry in FileHashes)
        {
            if(entry.Key != null)
            {
                foreach (var value in values)
                    FileHashes[entry.Key] = value;
            }
        }

        // If the file hash is different, the file has been modified.
        foreach (KeyValuePair<byte[], byte[]> entry in FileHashes)
        {
            if (entry.Key != entry.Value)
            {
                FileModified = true;
                NotifyObservers();
            }
        }
    }

    public static byte[] GetFileHash(string fileName)
    {
        HashAlgorithm sha1 = HashAlgorithm.Create();
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            return sha1.ComputeHash(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.1) do the trick for you?

Comment: The more files there are, and the larger each file it is, the longer it will take for your watcher to check for changes. And while checking for changes, it will be increasing the disk IO usage unnecessarily. I think you should look at registering to be notified when a file is changed, instead of polling for changes, as jdphenix suggests

Comment: For the record, your error is because you are enumerating `FileHashes` in a `foreach` and modifying the collection during the iteration. You can't do that. You'll need a nornal `for` loop if you want to do that.

Comment: Had no idea @pinkfloydx33, thank you! @jdphenix I'll give `FileSystemWatcher` another go. I was hoping to come up with a more custom solution but now that I look a little more this might work for what I need. Thanks!! :)

Comment: That's a terribly inefficient way to do things.  Why not go via **LastModified** file attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain what's likely giving you the error:

When you write a `foreach` loop like

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<byte[], byte[]> entry in FileHashes)
{
   // ...
}
```

this is really syntactic sugar for something like

```
 IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<byte[], byte[]>> enumerator = FileHashes.GetEnumerator(); 

 while(enumerator.MoveNext())
 {
     KeyValuePair<byte[], byte[]> = enumerator.Current;
     // ...
 }

 enumerator.Dispose();
```

Here the `enumerator` object can loop through the underlying collection, *provided that the underlying collection doesn't change.*  If it does, the enumerator is invalidated and the call to `enumerator.MoveNext()` throws an exception.

---

That said, it's not really clear to me what the code is meant to do.  For instance, the code

```
 foreach (var value in values)
      FileHashes[entry.Key] = value;
```

viewed alone, sets `FileHashes[entry.Key]` to whatever the last value in `values` is, since each iteration of the `foreach` loop will just overwrite the last one.

You might want to unpack what you're trying to do and making sure your code actually says what you want it to.

---

Some people have suggested using `FileSystemWatcher`, but this often won't work in practice, at least if dealing with every change is a hard requirement.

One obvious issue is that if your program stops and has to restart it obviously won't know about anything that happened when it was shut off.  Another is that if your program modifies the files it's watching, it will get notifications of its own activity, meaning you have to go to some trouble to distinguish what's causing the notifications.  A less obvious issue is that if you're watching a network drive and there's a blip in the network connection the files might change without you receiving a notification.

(I'm going from memory here, so some of the above may not be 100% correct, but hopefully the idea gets across.)

For these reasons I've always ended up having to do manual polling anyway.